# Problema con mysql, node y module.exports

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Eh . . . hola todo mundo, pues verán llevo como un día aprendiendo node así que si llego a decir tonterías y ser estúpido disculpen. Tengo un pequeño sitio que estoy conectando a mysql con node, pero pues para desahogar código pues quería utilizar modulo como en java pero pues tengo problemas.
La app hace un require a un js que cree que tiene una función que se se conecta a una BD y retorno (creo yo) el resultado, cuando mando a llamar a la función me retorna un null y después hace lo que solicito, es algo muy raro tal vez no estoy siendo muy descriptivo así que les dejaré el código, disculpen soy principiante.

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require("./conetionBD");
var app = express();

app.set('view engine','pug');
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname+"/css"));

app.get('/',(request,reponse)=>{
  console.log("Probando conexcion a mysql . . .");
  const ingredientes = mysql.getIngredients();
  console.log(ingredientes);
  console.log("Prueba terminada");
  //reponse.render('recetas',{ing:ingredientes });
  reponse.writeHead(200,{"Content-type":"text/html"});
  reponse.end();
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log("Servidor en linea");
```

connectionBD.js:

```
console.log("----Iniciando conexcion");
const mysql = require('mysql');
var ingredientes = null;
console.log("----Conecatcando");
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "zazem18",
  database: "cibus"
});
module.exports =  {
getIngredients: function(){
    var resultado = null;
    con.connect((err)=>{
      console.log("----Obteniendo datos, "+err);
      if(err) console.log("Error al conectarse");
      console.log("----Saltando error");
      con.query("select * from cat_units", (errr,result,field)=>{
        console.log("----Seleccionar datos");
        if(errr)console.log("Error al obtener datos");
        console.log(result);
        resultado = result;
      });
  });
  return resultado;
  }
}
```

Resultado en consola:

```
----Iniciando conexcion
----Conecatcando
Servidor en linea
Probando conexcion a mysql . . .
null
Prueba terminada
----Obteniendo datos, null
----Saltando error
----Seleccionar datos
[ RowDataPacket { id_uni: 1, uni_uni: 'cucharada' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 2, uni_uni: 'gramo' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 3, uni_uni: 'kilogramo' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 4, uni_uni: 'libra' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 5, uni_uni: 'litro' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 6, uni_uni: 'onza' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 7, uni_uni: 'onza l├â┬¡quida' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 8, uni_uni: 'taza' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 9, uni_uni: 'pieza' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 10, uni_uni: 'pisca' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 11, uni_uni: 'al gusto' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 12, uni_uni: 'manojo' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 13, uni_uni: 'hoja' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 14, uni_uni: 'Lata' },
  RowDataPacket { id_uni: 15, uni_uni: 'Loncha' } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

retorna **null** porque dentro de **getIngredients** se retorna **resultado** y resultado aun es nulo  en ese momento.

¿pero por qué resultado es null si antes hiciste la conexión y el query a la base de datos?

Lo que pasa es que la conexión a la base de datos y la respuesta no son inmediatas, así que todo el codígo que está dentro del **callback** del **query** no se va a ejecutar hasta que tu base de datos no haya respondido con **result**. Pero el codódigo que está por fuera como el **return resuldato**  si se va a ejecutar y como aún no se ha ejecutado **resuldado  = result**,  **resultado** seguira siendo **null**

Lo primero que hiciste fue declarar resultado como null que es el valor que va a tener mientras  espera a que el query se ejecute, la base de datos responda y el codigo dentro del callback del query se ejecute cambiandole el valor a result.

```
            getIngredients: function(){
                var resultado = null;
```

Todo lo que va dentro de el callback de con.conect no se va a ejecutar hasta que se haya echo la conexión o haya un error.

```
                con.connect((err)=>{
                  console.log("----Obteniendo datos, "+err);
                  if(err) console.log("Error al conectarse");
                  console.log("----Saltando error");
```

y todo lo que haya dentro de el callback de con.query no se va a ejecutar hasta que la base de datos no haya respondido con un result o un error

```
                  con.query("select * from cat_units", (errr,result,field)=>{
                    console.log("----Seleccionar datos");
                    if(errr)console.log("Error al obtener datos");
                    console.log(result);
                    resultado = result;
                  });
              });
```

Como retornas el resultado por fuera del callback del con.query, esta línea  se va a ejecutar sin importar si el query ya se hizo o no.

```
              return resultado;
              }
```

**CONCLUSIÓN y SOLUCIÓN**

js es un lenguaje asíncrono en el que hay mucha tareas que se ejecutan en segundo plano mientras el resto del código se sigue ejecutando. Este comportamiento es muy importante para trabajar con archivos, bases de datos, conexiones a otros servidores...

**La solución NO es poner el return dentro del callback del query**, este problema tiene muchas maneras de abordarse:

1) escribir todo el código que necesitas dentro del callback del query.

```
                con.query("select * from cat_units", (errr,result,field)=>{
                    console.log("----Seleccionar datos");
                    if(errr)console.log("Error al obtener datos");

                    //acá pongo todo mi codigo
                  });
```

2) pasarle un callback como parametro a tu funsión

```
            getIngredients: function(callback){
                var resultado = null;
                con.connect((err)=>{
                  console.log("----Obteniendo datos, "+err);
                  if(err) console.log("Error al conectarse");
                  console.log("----Saltando error");
                  con.query("select * from cat_units", (errr,result,field)=>{
                    console.log("----Seleccionar datos");
                    if(errr)console.log("Error al obtener datos");

                    callback(result);
                  });
              });
              }
```

la forma de llamar tu función sería por ejemplo:

```
mysql.getIngredients(console.log);
```

3) usando [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas)...